# Remove project name from URL YII?

Tags: php, yii

My Project URl is like

```
localhost/PROJECT-NAME/CONTROLLER-NAME/ACTION-NAME

localhost/test_ui/gifts/sendHere
```

I want to remove PROJECT-NAME from url.ie

```
 localhost/CONTROLLER-NAME/ACTION-NAME
 localhost/gifts/sendHere
```

I already remove index.php with the help of .htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /test_ui
 # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 # otherwise forward it to index.php
 RewriteRule . index.php
```

What can I do for it?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to follow two steps in order to achieve this.

Suppose the Project name is ProjectXYZ.
So there must be having a folder called ProjectXYZ containing all your project necessary files.

1. Cut all these files inside projectXYZ and **bring them outside the projectXYZ folder**.
   Now your ProjectXYZ folder must be empty. You can safely delete it now.
2. **open the Index.php file**. You will fine this line there

   `$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../framework/yii.php';`

change it to `$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/framework/yii.php';`

The project name is removed now.